# Como retornar o valor de type radio

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Bom dia !

Estou com um probleminha estou tentando retornar o value de um campo radio imprimindo na tela para dar um tipo de retorna para o usuário antes de efetuar o clique de envio.
Estou no momento testando em cima de um script que encontrei, porém sem muito sucesso está me retornando NaN, tentei alterar de parseInt para parseFlot porém ainda sem sucesso.

```
<form>
    <p>Now, with CSS3: </p>
    <div class="cc-selector">
        <input id="visa" type="radio" name="credit-card" value="20" onfocus="calcularPrimeiro()" />
        <label class="drinkcard-cc visa" for="visa"></label>
        <input id="mastercard" type="radio" name="credit-card" value="30" onblur="calcularPrimeiro()" />
        <label class="drinkcard-cc mastercard"for="mastercard"></label>
    </div>
</form>

<div id="resultado"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function calcularPrimeiro() {
  var n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementsByClassName('credit-card').value, 0);
  document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = n1;
}
</script>
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` retorna um array de elementos. Provavelmente o `.value` está retornando undefined.

Comment: Provavelmente sim, tentei dessa forma agora para entrar no array e exibir o valor, porém ainda sem sucesso me informa que o value esta sem nada declarado, function calcularPrimeiro() {
  var n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementsByClassName('credit-card'));
  var value = n1[0].value;
  document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = value;
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Ao invés de usar um `for` complexo** para fazer isto, basta usar `querySelector` para pegar o item que deseja, assim:

```
document.querySelector('input[name="credit-card"]:checked').value;
```

Se for jQuery, assim:

```
$('input[name="credit-card"]:checked').val();
```

---

Troque o `onblur` e `onfocus` por `onchange`, pois se não o evento vai ser executado antes de trocar o valor

```js
function calcularPrimeiro() {
  var input = document.querySelector('input[name="credit-card"]:checked');
  var n1 = parseFloat(input.value, 0);
  document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = n1;
}
```

```html
<div id="resultado"></div>

<form>
    <p>Now, with CSS3: </p>
    <div class="cc-selector">
        <input id="visa" type="radio" name="credit-card" value="20" onchange="calcularPrimeiro()" />
        <label class="drinkcard-cc visa" for="visa"></label>
        <input id="mastercard" type="radio" name="credit-card" value="30" onchange="calcularPrimeiro()" />
        <label class="drinkcard-cc mastercard"for="mastercard"></label>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, a primeira resposta usando loop já resolveu meu problema.

Comment: @RonaldoM prefere fazer um loop com muitas linhas ao invés de escrever apenas uma com querySelector? Acho que poderia rever isto com mais calma.

Comment: Realmente cara, testei novamente e fica bem menos complicado de implementar e funcionou para o que eu precisava, caso alguém necessite vou editar meu código de como ficou

Answer (score 1):

Se entendi bem, você deseja trazer um item pré selecionado, sendo assim, foi adicionado o `checked` no primeiro item e no *load* da página já é feita a chamada do método que retorna o valor selecionado. Também mudei a função para pegar os `radios` pelo nome e checar qual está selecionado. Quanto ao evento que dispara, mudei para o `onclick` porque assim, quando o usuário selecionar o item, será disparada a função.

```js
(function() {
      calcularPrimeiro()
})();

function calcularPrimeiro() {

 var radios = document.getElementsByName('credit-card');
 for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++)
 {
  if (radios[i].checked)
  {
   var n1 = radios[i].value;
      var itemId = radios[i].id;
   document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = itemId + " - " + n1;
   break;
  }
 }  
}
```

```html
<form>
    <p>Now, with CSS3: </p>
    <div class="cc-selector">
        <input id="visa" type="radio" checked name="credit-card" value="20" onclick="calcularPrimeiro()" />
        <label class="drinkcard-cc visa" for="visa">20</label>
        <input id="mastercard" type="radio" name="credit-card" value="30" onclick="calcularPrimeiro()" />
        <label class="drinkcard-cc mastercard"for="mastercard">30</label>
    </div>
</form>

</br>
</br>

<div>Resultado: <div id="resultado"></div></div>
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

Comment: Cara perfeito, somente mais uma duvida para que eu evite gambiarras, esta exibindo o valor correto, mas caso eu queira que exista mais uma variável no meio desse loop para saber o nome do que foi selecionado seria possível? Ou você acha melhor só comprar o valor recebido para descobrir isso? Acredito que não seja o melhor a se fazer porque o valor podem se repetir, resultando em um erro

Comment: @RonaldoM fiz uma edição na resposta pegando o Id do item, ele deve ser único, ai isso deve resolver o que você deseja

Comment: Obrigado vou testar aqui, enquanto isso fiz uma edição adicionando em if mais acredito que seja errado, segue o que eu tentei fazer: if (radios[i].checked)
  {
   var n1 = radios[i].value;
   if(n1=='primeiraOpcao'){
   document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = n1;
   }
   if(n1=='segundaOpcao'){
   document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = n1;
   }
   break;
  }

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado !

Comment: Encontrei um pequeno problema e ainda não consegui resolver, acredito que seja porque as variáveis declaradas dentro de for não ficam globais correto? Tenho mais alguns campos e não consigo fazer uma simples soma com outros valores de outras funções

Comment: Juntei tudo dentro da mesma função para conseguir pegar o valor da varial, entretanto parece que esta retornando em string e agora estou tentando transformar em float

Comment: var total = int(n1 + n2);
 document.getElementById('Total').innerHTML = total;

Comment: Nesse caso, seria melhor abrir outra pergunta no site com todo código lá, ai fica mais fácil para a galera conseguir ajudar. E fica mais organizado também.

Comment: Já consegui realizar o que necessitava obrigado !

Answer (score -1):

Realizei um teste e meio que funcionou da forma que eu quero, porém acredito que não seja a maneira correta e se irá funcionar caso eu tenha mais campos ou eu ia ter que encher de if.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
    <p>Now, with CSS3: </p>
    <div class="cc-selector">
        <input id="visa" type="radio" name="credit-card" value="10" onfocus="calcularPrimeiro()" />
        <label class="drinkcard-cc visa" for="visa" ></label>
        <input id="mastercard" type="radio" name="credit-card" value="20" onblur="calcularPrimeiro()" />
        <label class="drinkcard-cc mastercard"for="mastercard"></label>
    </div>
</form>

<div id="resultado"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function calcularPrimeiro() {
  var n1 = document.getElementById("visa").value;
  var n2 = document.getElementById("mastercard").value;
  if($(visa).prop("checked")){
  document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = n1;
}else{
    document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = n2;
}
}
</script>
```